# Possible ways to flag lines from csv file

Tags: c#

For a school assignment I am required to read a csv file, but not load it all in memory. After parsing the data I need to post them to an api. Now the requirement is that the data is only posted once. I want to flag the data before it is sent and again after it is posted. I am trying to research ways on how to do this but have not been successful. Any possible implementations?

I was looking in writing the flagged data on a separate file, then compare the two files and skip the lines that are flagged on the other file.

This is the main progam:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Book1.csv"))
{
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Book1.csv"))
{
    string line;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        //split the line by comma
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] split = line.Split(',');

        Field f1 = new Field();
        Field f2 = new Field();

        Payload payload = new Payload(new List<Field>() { f1, f2 }, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow);

        //Prepare the payload
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);

        var response = Request.Post(json);
        if (response.Result != true)
        {
            tsError.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 3, "Error Occured");
        }
        else
        {
            ts.TraceInformation("completed");
        }
        
        ts.Flush();
        tsError.Flush();
    }
}}
```

Comment: I'll just provide a step to the desired direction: You want to create some "object", that will hold `Data` and information `WasItPostedToAPI`. Since you shouldn't keep all initial data in memory (could take lot of space), you can probably just remember some information for each data that represents "the row". Something like `ID` or `Name`. Once you have all this, what will be needed next?

Comment: Btw. SO is site related to programmers question where you have concrete issue "I don't know how to create a class" and usually receive an answer. Your current question is super ambigious and have several approaches // is not really technical. SO is not site to answer homeworks. You should consider that, try to work it yourself and if you are blocked at any stage, do the research. If even after that you are not sure, ask the question for particular detail in implementation where you are stuck. This is how we all work.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. I managed to implement the necessary features. To make my self clear, I got stuck in the part (which I should of mentioned) where if the program is stopped completely, how can it resume from where it stopped and not post data has been already posted. I had found a way to save the last line posted but was told that it was not enough.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.